# Check if two different cell values exist in the same row and return a different element from that row

Tags: excel, vlookup, cross-reference

I am working on a report that shows the ordering patterns of a consumer base. I'm trying to find the last and first orders that these consumers are making. I have the contact name and the dates of the first and last orders provided. I also have a list of all transactions that contains the contact names and sale dates in conjunction with the sale totals.

My idea is there should be a way to cross reference these and return the sales totals for the column where both the date and contact match up.I've tried VLOOKUP and a few other functions but I dont think they work since there are more than one order from the contacts.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need `SUMIF` (or `SUMIFS`).

Comment: I agree with dwirony that `SUMIFS` is probably what you need. `SUMIFS` essentially performs multiple `VLOOKUPS` and sums together all values that meet the criteria.